# jquery slideshow won't cycle through more than once

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have a slideshow on my website with 10 slides & 10 corresponding captions underneath the slides & a next button and previous button. When you click on the next button, the slideshow will cycle thru the 10 slides then it goes blank. Can anyone help me fix this problem. Thanks, Ron

Here is the html:

```
<body style="font-family: Arial, Sans-serif, sans;">

<!-- this will work with any number of images -->
<!-- set the active class on whichever image you want to show up as the default 
(otherwise this will be the last image) -->

<h2>Top 10 Vechicles Among US-Hispanics</h2><br />


<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="active">
        <img src="img/banner01.jpg" alt="Toyota Corolla" /></a>
        <br><strong>1. Toyota Corolla</strong><br>
The 2013 Toyota Corolla is a study in practicality and stylish engineering.
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="img/banner02.jpg" alt="Honda Civic" /></a>
        <br><strong>2. Honda Civic</strong><br>
The Honda Civic, a longtime favorite sedan among fuel-conscious drivers.
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="img/banner03.jpg" alt="Honda Accord" /></a>
        <br /><strong>3. Honda Accord</strong><br>
The 2013 Honda Accord proved to be popular with drivers and professional reviewers.
    </div>

    <div>
        <img src="img/banner04.jpg" alt="Toyota Camry" /></a>
        <br /><strong>4. Toyota Camry</strong><br>

The Toyota Camry is one of the best-selling vehicles of all time.
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/banner05.jpg" alt="Ford F-Series" /></a>
        <br /><strong>5. Ford F-Series</strong><br>
The Ford F-Series of pickups has put a huge fleet of tough trucks.
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/banner06.jpg" alt="Nissan Sentra" /></a>
        <br /><strong>6. Nissan Sentra</strong><br>
The 2013 Nissan Sentra drives up in six models, from the basic S.
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/banner07.jpg" alt="Nissan Altima" /></a>
        <br /><strong>7. Nissan Altima</strong><br>
The midsize Nissan Altima was completely made over for the 2013 model.
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/banner08.jpg" alt="Chevrolet Silverado" /></a>
        <br /><strong>8. Chevrolet Silverado</strong><br>
The 2013 Chevy Silverado, with a starting price of $23,590 for the two-wheel-drive 1500 model.
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/banner09.jpg" alt="Honda CR-V" /></a>
        <br /><strong>9. Honda CR-V</strong><br>
With its tight turning radius, carlike handling and roomy interior.
    </div>
     <div>
        <img src="img/banner10.jpg" alt="Nissan Versa" /></a>
        <br /><strong>10. Nissan Versa</strong><br>
The 2013 Nissan Versa scores big points for its affordability.
    </div>

</div>


 <div id="nav"></div>
                <div id="button-previous">prev</div>
            <div id="button-next">next</div>
```

Here is the J code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

/*** 
    Simple jQuery Slideshow Script
    Released by Jon Raasch (jonraasch.com) under FreeBSD license: free to use or modify, not responsible for anything, etc.  Please link out to me if you like it :)
***/



$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sp').first().addClass('active');
$('.sp').hide();    
$('.active').show();

    $('#button-next').click(function(){

    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
                   if ( $('.oldActive').is(':last-child')) {
        $('.sp').first().addClass('active');
        }
        else{
        $('.oldActive').next().addClass('active');
        }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();


    });

       $('#button-previous').click(function(){
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('oldActive');    
           if ( $('.oldActive').is(':first-child')) {
        $('.sp').last().addClass('active');
        }
           else{
    $('.oldActive').prev().addClass('active');
           }
    $('.oldActive').removeClass('oldActive');
    $('.sp').fadeOut();
    $('.active').fadeIn();
    });




});

</script>
```

Here is the css code:

```
<style type="text/css">

/*** set the width and height to match your images **/

#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:560px;
    width:620px;
}

#slideshow DIV {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
    opacity:0.0;
    height: 560px;
    width:620px;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#slideshow DIV.active {
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1.0;
}

#slideshow DIV.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}

#slideshow DIV IMG {
    height: 350px;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#nav {margin-top:20px; width:100%;}
#button-previous {float:left;margin-left:200px;}
#button-next {float:right;margin-right:200px;}


</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code relies on the sp class to function correctly.

You need to add the sp class to each of your slideshow divs like this:

```
<div class="sp">
   <img src="img/banner01.jpg" alt="Toyota Corolla" /></a>
    <br><strong>1. Toyota Corolla</strong><br>
    The 2013 Toyota Corolla is a study in practicality and stylish engineering.
</div>
```

Without it the code isn't able to find the first or last element.

Comment: Ryan, thanks, that was it, works perfectly now! Hey, can I ask you another question.... I noticed that when the mouse hoovers over the next & prev text, it doesn't turn into a mouse pointer... any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Ryan, pointer works perfectly. Thanks so much for all your help!